# does react native release mode must have hosted api / db?

Tags: android, react-native, release

im quite new on react native and i want to build this app so it can run remotely on device  , on debug everything went fine, it uses api and xampp mysql for db

when i try to build apk release and run npx react-native run-android --variant=Release the build is successful but when i open the app it instantly crashed

im wondering if it because my api and db still not hosted yet , must it hosted first and only then u can release it ? i kinda want to try it on device before hosting my db and api

i try adb logcat *:E and this is what i got

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lv4X2U4QjMyeNMlNTo5jDe243pUMALbl/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it , it just need to use axios https instead of axios http
and i import usestate wrong , bcs its automatic

i've actually tried this before but i think i've tried this fix separately and i already reverted one of them with git , so i thought 2 of these things is not the solution

tried 2 of them again today bcs of desperate  and thankfully it worked